# Superposition of two images

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I implemented the application of one picture for several pixels. Already tried to do it through Stack - but then part of the top image overlaps. The pictures need to be in an 8:1 ratio. Tell me, please, what layout of widgets can I try to implement this?

How it should look

[image]

What does it look like now

[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Image.asset(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill, "images/someimage1.png")),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child:
                      Image.asset(fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, "images/someimage2.png")),
            ],
          ),
       ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: About your attached desire output, It contains 3 items

Comment: There are actually 2 objects in the output. I made the second object semi-transparent to show how it overlaps the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LayoutBuilder` with `Stack` widget.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              height: constraints.maxHeight * .8,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          /// widget render priority bottom to top
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              width: constraints.maxWidth,
              height: constraints.maxHeight * .2 +
                  20, //20 px extra for middle overlap
              color: Colors.purple.withOpacity(.5),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

[image]

More about [flutter layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Answer (score 0):

Use flexfit tight

```dart
Flexible(
  flex: 8,
  fit: FlexFit.tight,
  child: Image.asset(""),
);
```